# Invalid default value for timestamp column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, timestamp

I can't find why this is not valid in MySQL 5.7 (tested with 5.7.16)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE() VALUES ();
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_TEST;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST SELECT * FROM (SELECT ts FROM TEST_TABLE) wrap;
```

I am getting this: Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'ts'

Am I missing something or is it a mysql bug?

Comment: works for me...

Comment: for me too http://rextester.com/RLDT26402

Comment: Dont know why you need `TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST` because you didnt use. But you miss a semicolon there `;`

Comment: Assuming they're actually handled as 4 different statements, `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST` triggers *A table must have at least 1 column* for me. Is this real code or just a simplified test case?

Comment: not missing a semicolon, the lines 4 and 5 are one single statement

Comment: this is the closest workaround I can find but I am not happy with that and I don't understand why I would need to cast to datetime anyways:
`CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE() VALUES (); DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_TEST; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(ts AS DATETIME) FROM TEST_TABLE) wrap;`

Comment: can you create something in rextester to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.16    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE() VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM (SELECT ts FROM TEST_TABLE) wrap;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2016-11-04 00:00:01 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_TEST;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST;
ERROR 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column
```

**UPDATE**

After you update your question:

```
mysql> SELECT ts FROM TEST_TABLE;
Field   1:  `ts`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `test`
Table:      `TEST_TABLE`
Org_table:  `TEST_TABLE`
Type:       TIMESTAMP
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     19
Max_length: 19
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY TIMESTAMP 

+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2016-11-04 00:00:01 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM (SELECT ts FROM TEST_TABLE) wrap;
Field   1:  `ts`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `test`
Table:      `wrap`
Org_table:  `*`
Type:       TIMESTAMP
Collation:  utf8_general_ci (33)
Length:     57
Max_length: 19
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY TIMESTAMP 

+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2016-11-04 00:00:01 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Note the difference in **Collation**.

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST
    -> SELECT * FROM (SELECT BINARY ts FROM TEST_TABLE) wrap;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**UPDATE 2**

When the query attempts to create the temporary table, the subquery causes the default value of `ts` column is defined as `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` and the server must be configured in the variable `SQL_MODE` the `NO_ZERO_DATE` value, which causes the error.

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('NO_ZERO_DATE', @@SQL_MODE);
+-----------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('NO_ZERO_DATE', @@SQL_MODE) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       4 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Remove `NO_ZERO_DATE` from `SQL_MODE`.

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('NO_ZERO_DATE', @@SQL_MODE);
+-----------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('NO_ZERO_DATE', @@SQL_MODE) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       0 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_TEST;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST
    -> SELECT * FROM (SELECT ts FROM TEST_TABLE) wrap;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE TMP_TEST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: TMP_TEST
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TMP_TEST` (
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

You can avoid the problem by removing the subquery.

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('NO_ZERO_DATE', @@SQL_MODE);
+-----------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('NO_ZERO_DATE', @@SQL_MODE) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       4 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_TEST;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST
    -> SELECT ts FROM TEST_TABLE;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE TMP_TEST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: TMP_TEST
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TMP_TEST` (
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks but this is not the code I posted... what you are doing is something different. The error you got (1113) is expected since you don't declare any columns to your temp table. To reproduce the issue, you need to execute statements in same sequence and lines 4 & 5 together (it's one single statement)

Comment: Just edited my question to avoid confusion. Issue happens on last statement.

Comment: @romric: Updated answer.

Comment: sounds like a clue on the issue but still not 100% sure to understand. so when using the second select, the collation is somehow changed? How is that interfering with the default value of timestamp defined? Btw, how do you print this useful field details?

Comment: @romric: Updated answer and you can use [--column-type-info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_column-type-info) option from [5.5.1 mysql - The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I still need the subquery as my use case is obviously more complicated than this so I just removed NO_ZERO_DATE from sql_mode and it works fine now.  Now the only thing  I don't understand is why MySQL is defaulting the timestamp with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'...